# How I can do this url in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

I have a problem in laravel, route url

```
Route::get('/soru/{qhead}/{qid}','SingleQuestionController@get_index');
```

How can I do URL like this `/soru/kategori/{cat}`?

I tried this but doesnt work:

```
Route::get('/soru/kategori/{cat}','QuestionCategoryController@get_index');
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what error are you seeing?

Comment: Route::get('/soru/{qhead}/{qid}','SingleQuestionController@get_index'); first used this url, laravel is try access this url. does not see the second uri

Comment: what are the types of qhead ?

Comment: Please elaborate your problem correctly to make it more clear to understand. Give some more information on each phases of your problem.